# Template extension renders but not new code

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm building a Craigslist clone following someone else's work and I'm having trouble extending a template. The template in fact renders but I'm including an h2 text to test it and the only thing that renders is the template itself but not the h2 or anything I try to add to it. Other people that ran into the same issue had, for example, a typo on their urlspattern but mine seems to be correct and also matches the work I'm following. Let me know if there's something else I should share that might help to clarify it. Thanks in advance!

Base.html is the template I'm extending and New_search.html is the view I'm trying to extend the template to. This is the code itself:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<h2>"NEW SEARCH"</h2>

{% block content %}

{% endblock content %}
```

**my_app/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('new_search', views.new_search, name='new_search'),
]
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we extend a template to another, Django first fills the HTML page with the content of the base template. Then, it searches for the "block" tags and if the child template contains the same block, then it replaces the contents of this block tag in the base template with that of the child template.
Since you are defining the h2 tag outside of any block in the child template, Django won't use it. You can use the h2 tag inside the block content, or make another block in the base template to use it separately.